# Not getting expected result at Apache solar search

Tags: php, solr, drupal-7

I have recently upgraded Apache solr server from 4.3.1 to 5.5. I am trying to search the user by Email ID. The below query is working in 4.3.1 and showing exact match of abc@gmail.com but in 5.5 it is showing matching result.

```
fq=bundle:(user)&fq=!entity_id:[52115 TO 57116]&q=abc@gmail.com*&hl=true&sort=hs_weight desc&qf=full_name^5.0 sap_code^5.0 ts_name^5.0 ts_mail^5.0&defType=edismax&lowercaseOperators=true&rows=100&start=0&wt=json&json.nl=map
```

How to fix this ?

Comment: Are you sure the field types in your schema are the same? It's hard to tell from your question about what you're seeing that you didn't expect, but it sounds like it's from a matching against a `text` field instead of a `string` field. I'd probably also recommend doing the full upgrade to a more recent version than 5.5 if you're going to go down the route of updating your schema and types.

Comment: I have similar issue with solr 5.5. If my string having special character it is not fetching results like abc_cd@gmail.com

Comment: @GirijaS That is specific to the schema defined for that field. It's not related to the version, except for the fact that you upgraded and didn't get the same field definitions in your new schema.

Comment: @MatsLindh , Schema for that field is same for both in version Field-Type:org.apache.solr.schema.TextFieldDocs:132426
Flags: Indexed Tokenized Stored TermVector Stored
Schema    
Index

Comment: @GirijaS Feel free to ask your own question with the appropriate details, but a TextField is usually tokenized according to the Tokenizer defined. If the tokenizer splits on that character (which the StandardTokenizer and similar does), then the results will depend on what the processing rules are. If it's a `string` field or a text field with a `keywordtokenizer` attached, only exact matches will be returned. But please add your own question with all appropriate details; the comments of a different question is not the place to discuss this.